# Beginner question on why my dictionary isn't working

Tags: dictionary

So I'm crash coursing myself though Python and I dont understand why this isn't going through the right way:

```
>favorite_numbers = {
    'mike': 15,
    'john': 97
}
print("Mike's favorite number is " + favorite_numbers['mike'].title() + ".")
print("John's favorite number is " + favorite_numbers['john'].title() + ".")
```

It comes up as:

'int' object has no attribute 'title'

Is there some syntax I'm missing? I'm doing it exactly as the book says. I'm sorry this is so beginner but I want to be really thorough in my understanding.

Comment: What are you wanting `title` to do? Is this book showing the values in `favorite_numbers` being class instances? `favorite_numbers['mike']` will evaluate to `15`, and `15`  (an int) doesn't have a `title` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It's not clear what you're trying to do with ".title()" on the two references to favorite_numbers.  Not only is it not needed, it's incorrect.

```
>favorite_numbers = {
    'mike': 15,
    'john': 97
}
print("Mike's favorite number is " + favorite_numbers['mike'] + ".")
print("John's favorite number is " + favorite_numbers['john'] + ".")
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense once you point it out, I didn't notice it before.